# Is it legal to selectively enforce an arbitrary dress code for a specific employee?

Tags: united-states, manager, dress-code

I work at a university in the USA. I am a man in my early 30s, but most of the people with whom I work are men in their late 30s or early 40s. I look young for my age and am often mistaken for a student. Because of this my boss insists I wear business casual university-brand attire every day so that everyone recognizes me as an employee. No one else is required to do this and is allowed to dress casually. What's more, I was required to purchase clothing from the university store with my own money. Is this legal? How should I communicate that I dislike this policy, and to whom?

Comment: do you have an employee handbook or contract? If it's not stated it shouldn't apply. what sort of job (what is the tile of your boss-vague is fine)?

Comment: I will let someone else handle the US labour law question, but you could also consider that the direction is just (perhaps forceful, perhaps misguided) advice by a boss trying to help you in an early-ish stage in your career. You also haven't mentioned what other clothes you have been wearing to the office. Either way a direct conversation would be a good first step.

Comment: This sounds very much like "discrimination" - talk to HR... Or talk to a lawyer...

Comment: Please say the state/country you're in. In California, you can sue for wage theft two years after the fact (yes, wage theft. I explain why this is considered wage theft in California below). And you don't need to sue, you can just make a complaint with Labor Commissioner. Their website even shows the example of a waitress who made a complaint for being forced to buy her own name tag for $20 ($20, that's all it took). That example is in their PDF. But you'll need proof, so be sure to memorialize what happened over email. If there is no contemporaneous proof, it will be difficult to do anything

Comment: With that said, not all labor department/labor commissioners are the same. Some are severely understaffed (even if the law is on your side). That's why you need to tell us where you're located. So if you want an easier solution, just grow a beard or a mustache (assuming you can grow one). Or maybe talk to your Union if you have one.

Comment: Close voters: This is a question about employment law, not company policy or legal advice.

Comment: Even if you look like a student, that does not affect your job performance. Is it true ? People who work with you daily and security personnel should be familiar with you after 1 or 2 weeks, and there should be no issue. I am not sure why your boss thinks that it is more beneficial for you to change your outfit ?

Comment: BTW, if you wear clothes purchased from the university with the university logo or mascot on the clothes, that may even make you look a lot more like a student having fun on the campus ground.

Answer (score 19):

> How should I communicate that I dislike this policy, and to whom?

My strategy when asked to do something I thought outside my role and would inconvenience me (cost me money), was to just ignore it. Usually it just went away quietly.

When it didn't and I was put under pressure I'd just ask who was paying for it because I couldn't afford it.

If they delayed answering I'd go back to ignoring it.

If they wanted me to pay for it, I'd tell them it will have to wait until I have some spare money, then go back to ignoring it.

Comment: Agreed, don't make this a formal issue, but you could make a minor change to your day-to-day outfits so they look a little less like those of a student; nothing drastic or expensive, just a small gesture which might make your boss a bit more happy.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check your state laws - that'd be called a "uniform".  In my state (California) employers are required to reimburse employees for uniforms or required clothing.

You could Google for more depth, but also look [here](https://www.employmentlawfirms.com/resources/do-i-have-pay-a-uniform-bearing-company-logo.htm)

Comment: It’s only a uniform if “everyone” has to wear it.

Comment: @AsheraH Like a single security guard working at a bank, right? (smile)

Comment: @XavierJ If OP is the only one that has to do that and their colleagues have the same job descriptions, that's a whole other situation